# Concatena las cadenas en C

Tags: array, c

¿Cómo puedo concatenar dos cadenas dejando un espacio en blanco entre medias?

Ejemplo:

- Cadena1: `Hola`
- Cadena2: `Mundo`
- Salida deseada: `Hola Mundo`

He estado usando `strcat (cadena1, cadena2)` pero esto me saca

> HolaMundo

Conocéis alguna forma para solucionarlo.

PD: Tanto `cadena1` como `cadena2` están definidas como `char cadenaX[250]`, donde `X` es el número de la cadena.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen dia, puedes hacer:

```
String cadena = strcat (cadena1, " ");
cadena = strcat(cadena1, cadena2);
```

O tambien es lo mismo:

```
    String cadena = strcat (cadena1, strcat(" ", cadena2));
```

Comment: Miiil graciassss

Comment: @Franco Rolando Fijate que la segunda opcion que das no es correcta. `strcat(" ", cadena2)` trata de escribir sobre un `const char *`. Ese es comportamiento indefinido

Comment: @Pablochaches gracias por la correcion

Comment: El tipo `String` en C no existe.

Comment: @MrDave1999 el concepto se entendio jaja hace mucho no uso C